# Objective C syntax issue related to parameter not getting right data

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've been working on a project implementing Hola CDN framework. I'm now running into an issue that I can't pass on current date to the parameter programDay and I traced the source code and I found the below line. What does this below line mean?

```
self.programDay = ![dict[GETPROGRAMLISTDATA_PROGRAMEDAY] isEqual:[NSNull null]] ? dict[GETPROGRAMLISTDATA_PROGRAMEDAY] : nil;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.programDay = ![dict[GETPROGRAMLISTDATA_PROGRAMEDAY] isEqual:[NSNull null]] ? dict[GETPROGRAMLISTDATA_PROGRAMEDAY] : nil;
```

This line means that if `[dict[GETPROGRAMLISTDATA_PROGRAMEDAY]` has empty value or null value the nil would be assign to `self.programDay` as there would be value of `[dict[GETPROGRAMLISTDATA_PROGRAMEDAY]` will be assign to `self.programDay`. Usually (null) value is return from webservice if that value is not presented in database on server.

Answer (score 2):

**What's NSNull**
`[NSNull null]` doesn't equal to `nil`. It means empty value. For example,
`@[[NSNull null]].count` equals to 1. `NSNull` is used as placeholder in `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`. It means nil.
**For your question**
This line is used to replace `NSNull` with nil.

Comment: I don't think I understand. Can you please try to relate to dict[GETPROGRAMLISTDATA_PROGRAMEDAY]? Perhaps it'd help me understood. Thanks.

Comment: @SanitLee Updated my answer.